# setOnclcikListener not working in Services what i do?

Tags: android, service

I am making a custom screen call app which will work in services i need two button in services i call that buttons but button click not working in services what i do now?

Service Class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private View view;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("inez","inez onCreate");
        super.onCreate();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0,
            0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            0,
            // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textview.setText("Someone is calling: " + intent.getStringExtra("incomingNumber"));
        textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        wm.addView(view, params);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.removeView(view);
    }

}
```

Comment: provide full code..

Comment: button code not show

Comment: it's not possible service is a background thread .

Comment: if u want click event write foreground service u will access via notification.

Comment: Use Service for background work, like API calls or geting data from database. Make UI operations in main thread (Activity, Fragment).